# Can I make it happen that when I check a checkbox I created in a cell it will not display that checked item anymore?

Tags: google-sheets

This all should happen in a cell.

I have several items in checkboxes that when i select one or multiple it will not display that item anymore in the cell

For example, this cell will contain:

Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
Option 4
Option 5

When I select options 1 and 4 it will disappear from the selection and just display options 2,3 and 5 and make the checkboxes disappear as well. And can I make it so that when I make a mistake I can revert it to have all the options to checkboxes again.

I don't even know if this is possible.

Comment: One cell can contain only one checkbox. So, where do you get 5 checkboxes/options in 1 cell?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be confusing the Google Sheets cell **data validation** options. Below, I will only mention the two that are relevant to this question:

- A **checkbox** can only have two valid values. The default valid values are TRUE and FALSE. Note: A blank cell with a checkbox is displayed as unchecked.
- A **dropdown** can have multiple valid values. It could use a list of valid values or could use a cell range as the source of valid values.

Considering the above, it's more probable that you are referring to a dropdown. To achieve what you are looking for, you should set the **dropdown** to use a cell range as the source of the valid values. This range should include a formula using **FILTER**, **QUERY** or another way to include only the values that you want to display.

Please read the Googl**e Sheets help center articles about** data validation and the functions mentioned above. You can find these articles in your spreadsheet by

1. Click the **Help** menu, then Sheets help
2. On the search box, type **data validation**

   [image: Sheets help > data validation]
3. Read the article "Create an in-cell dropdown list" first.

Then, do the same to learn about Google Sheets' functions **FILTER** and/or **QUERY**.

Comment: Yes that is what I was referring to. Thank you very much! I'm actually at a lost and i'm now on the right track. I was actually drinking when I was looking into this yesterday. crazy how alcohol disables your thinking